# java.util.logging.Logger and org.apache.log4j.Logger in one application - will the first one log as log4j?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, guava

I have written a method for closing files

```
private void closeFiles(Closeable ... files) {
    for (Closeable file : files) {
        if (file != null) {
            try {
                file.close();
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                // org.apache.log4j.Logger
                logger.error("Unable to close file.", ioe);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and then I found out that Guava provides the `closeQuietly` method which basicaly does the same thing. The only difference is using `java.util.logging.Logger` for logging. If an exception occurs in Guava, will it be logged into a file (configured for `log4j`) or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think not. You has to write own handler. See for example
[Routing java.util.logging messages to Log4J](http://shrubbery.mynetgear.net/c/display/W/Routing+java.util.logging+messages+to+Log4J)

Comment: Yep.   It depends on how logging is configured.   It isn't generally a good idea to bind to Log4J directly anymore.   Best to use SLF4J or JULI.